# Why doesn't Firebase Analytics pass IDFA if Android app can?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I'm getting app events through `Firebase analytics` on Android, and when I query the data in `BigQuery` I find that many (not all) of the devices don't have a "resettable_device_id" (which is the IDFA according to:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en).

When I look in the app's database I do see identifiers that don't appear in `BigQuery`, but I know these are IDFAs because they match some of the `BigQuery` identifiers.

The app developer says that he gets the identifiers I see in the database from Play services, and he can't help with the Firebase side because the identifier is sent automatically by the SDK.

Why can't I get the identifiers? Can I change something in order to get them?